# rev() in r and how to apply it to a list using loops

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I have a list of say {a,b,c,d,...} and each element, a,b,c,d, ...  are `data.table` that I need to reverse the order of, however, for the `data.table` I only want to `rev()` all of it except the first column, as it is an `ID`. I tried using loops to do it but it returned

```
Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, , -1, value = list(code_a = c("a",  : 
  Item 1 of column numbers in j is -1 which is outside range [1,ncol=4]. Use column names instead in j to add new columns.
```

Example:

```
a <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
b <- 1:6
c <- c("F","E","D","C","B","A")
d <- 10:15
dt1 <- data.table("ID" = b, "code_a" = a)
dt2 <- data.table("ID" = b, "code_c" = c)
dt3 <- data.table("ID" = b, "code_d" = d)
dt <- list(dt1,dt2,dt3)
rev_dt <- rev(dt)
merged_list <- list()
rev_merged_list <- list()
rev_merged_list <- Reduce(merge, rev_dt, accumulate = TRUE)
merged_list <- rev_merged_list
merged_list <- rev(merged_list)

for(z in 1:length(dt)){
  merged_list[[z]][,-1] = rev(merged_list[[z]][,-1])
}
```

More Information:

The for loop here is supposed to be:
- for `z` from 1 to the length of `dt`
- the `merged_list` element z (which with double square brackets) should be a `data.table`
- where the data does not include the first column
- should be assigned to the rev of the same element z, where the first column is also excluded

Does this logic hold for the above loop? I am unsure what is wrong!

Expected Output:

```
output_ <- list()
a_ <- data.table("ID" = b, "code_a" = a, "code_c" = c, "code_d" = d)
b_ <- data.table("ID" = b, "code_c" = c, "code_d" = d)
c_ <- data.table("ID" = b, "code_d" = d)
output_[[1]] <- a_
output_[[2]] <- b_
output_[[3]] <- c_
output_
```

I was told yesterday that the merge above i can specify a right hand merge, however in doing so, I need to specify a `by = "ID"` in the merge, but I am unsure what is the `x` and `y` values in the case of merging multiple sets of data.

I am also under the impression that `lapply()` can do the same thing instead of loop, but I am unsure in this case how might I achieved that. Thanks~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `setcolorder`

```
for(i in seq_along(merged_list)){
   setcolorder(merged_list[[i]],
         c(names(merged_list[[i]])[1], rev(names(merged_list[[i]])[-1])))
   }

all.equal(merged_list, output_, check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: So let me try explain that for loop in words, and correct me if I am wrong here.

(1) for i where we take the length of the merged_list, as `seq_along` gives 1:length(merged_list)

(2) `merged_list` element i (a `data.table`) is assigned to:

(3) using `setcolorder(x,neworder = key(x))`

(4) x is a `data.table` which is `merged_list data.table` i

(5) where the key is a list where the `"ID"` column is and the rest of the `merged_list`

What I am unsure about is why is there a need for the function `names()`? Thanks alot

Comment: @Kazusa12345 Yes, `seq_along` returns the same as `1:length` but it is more solid  than 1:length when there are NULL list elements etc.  the `setcolorder` orders the columns based on the index or column names that we provide.  Actually the assignment is also needed here as it does on the fly

Comment: Sorry, not to familiar with the language just yet, what does it mean by "the assignment is also needed here as it does on the fly" in this context. Thanks

Comment: @Kazusa12345  the `set` functions does assignment by reference and don't need the `<-`

Comment: Ah thank you, can you also explain to me why `names()` is needed here?

Comment: @Kazusa12345  Not really needed.  You can also use index for column position.